# Add operation to graph without with-as-clause

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, graph

Since you are able to do a

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    #  Run stuff here with sess.run()
```

but also

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
sess.run(x)
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to do a similar thing with Graph creation, like:

```
a_graph = tf.Graph()
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='test')
a_graph.add(x)
```

The conventional way to add a node/operation to a graph is of course...

```
with a_graph.as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='test')
```

I couldn't read anything about this in the docs.. and `dir(a_graph)` does not show me a simple `.add()` method. The only thing I could think of are add some operation to a collection... but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always possible to enter/exit the context manager manually:

```py
# Enter the `graph` context
cm = graph.as_default()
cm.__enter__()

print(tf.get_default_graph() == graph)  # True

# All nodes are added to the `graph` now
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='y')

# Exit the context
cm.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

But `with` statement version looks much nicer to me though.

Comment: Yes I agree on your last statement, but I want to know all my options.

And thanks for editing my question :)